Qt application fails to initialize XCB plugin in WSL2
I have a WSL2 environment set up with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Windows 11 23H2. Previously, I was able to run my Qt5 application without any issues. However, I encountered a requirement for Qt4 in another program, which led me to uninstall Qt5 and install Qt4. After fulfilling that requirement and reinstalling Qt5, I started experiencing problems launching my Qt5 application.
The error message I'm receiving is as follows:
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 127.0.0.42:0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

I have attempted to set the DISPLAY environment variable based on the IP address found in my /etc/resolv.conf file, as shown below:
host_ip=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep -o -E "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}")
export DISPLAY=$host_ip:0

Has anyone encountered a similar situation, or can anyone provide guidance on how to properly configure the environment for running Qt5 applications in WSL2 after switching between Qt versions?

I've had issues with wsl2 where /tmp/.X11-unix is somehow changed to an empty directory instead of a symlink to /mnt/wslg/.X11-unix like it should be that causes similar errors.

I was not aware that earlier versions of WSL required manual configuration for X11, but as the version has been updated, this functionality has been embedded into WSL. I updated the WSL version yesterday, which is why I encountered this issue. The solution was to remove the content related to DISPLAY
host_ip=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep -o -E "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}")
export DISPLAY=$host_ip:0

from my .bashrc file.
